# How to pass JS variables into AJAX data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a simple page with employees names and you can drag them around using Jquery UI draggable.  I'm getting the "top" and "left" position of the dragged item and putting it into a JS variable.

I then want to pass those two variables into the AJAX data (so that update-db.php can use that info) but not sure how to do that.

```
  $( function() {

    $('.employee').draggable({
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            var left = $(this).position().left;
            var top = $(this).position().top;


           //Make ajax call here:
            $.ajax({
                  url: 'update-db.php',
                  type: 'POST',
                  data: ??????,   
             });
        }
    }).resizable({
        stop:function(event,ui){}
    })
  } );
```

Can anyone help? I'm very new to AJAX and struggling with the "data" part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change you ajax call like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'update-db.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {leftPosition: left, topPosition: top }   
});
```

this will send an object with the variables to the server. But that's not enough. It's also interesting you treat the success and failure of the ajax request. You could do that like this:

You should change you ajax call like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'update-db.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {leftPosition: left, topPosition: top }   
});
```

this will send an object with the variables to the server. But that's not enough. It's also interesting you treat the success and failure of the ajax request. You could do that like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'update-db.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {leftPosition: left, topPosition: top }   
    success: function() { console.log('OK'); },
    error: function() { console.log('Fail!'); })
});
```

or even better:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'update-db.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {leftPosition: left, topPosition: top }   
}).done(function() {
   console.log('OK');
}).fail(function() {
   console.log('Fail!');
});
```

obviously you should do something more interesting in the done and fail functions besides log the event to console.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $.ajax({
                  url: 'update-db.php',
                  type: 'POST',
                  data: {nameOfLeftKey: left, nameOfToptKey: top }   
             });
        }
```

The data field takes a javascript object(key value pair).  Here this code is assigning the value you stored in the var left to the key nameOfLeftKey.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value and makes it a ***good answer***.

Comment: Also the names of the variables are left and top, not left and right.

Comment: Good call guys I adjusted the answer.